# C# gathering multiple files into one

Tags: c#, xml, file

I'm working on a project whose concept is basically to act like a file container and gather files into one. 
So far, I created a "container" file, which has 2mb allocated at the beginning for indexing files. This part is a simple piece of XML where i store info such as filename, offset, filesize, etc. The rest is files added to the container forked after the 2mb allocated.

Currently, if I create a container and add files, it works like a charm. Problem is, if i want to add some more, the XmlDocument will erase rest of the content after saving.

My question is : should i use XML to do the index, and if yes, how to update it with no loss or should I proceed differently ?

Thanks for you your advices !

Comment: Where does the XmlDocument come into this? Looks like an XY question

Comment: When you add a new one, are you sure you're referencing your own index and know to start writing at "last index + last document length"?

Comment: Your question is unclear to me. Your core problem seems to be that the rest of your file(?) is deleted after you edit the XML index part at its beginning? Please add some code that shows how you do that.

Answer (score 5):

I think you should look to the SharpZipLib before reinventing the wheel.

For the answer on you question, you should save the xml first to a memorystream, then copy that stream to your file. (this way you'll know if you exceed 2mb size)
I wouldn't advise xml for this, also 2mb as starter size is pretty much. 
I would use something like a binaryreader/writer

This is only for example:

```
public class FileData
{
    public string Filename { get; set; }
    public int Size {get; set; }
    public int ContainerFileOffset { get; set; }
}

List<FileData> files = new List<FileData>();

using(Stream stream = new ...Stream(...))
{
    BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(stream);

    writer.Write(files.Count);
    foreach(FileData fd in files)
    {
        writer.Write(Filename);
        writer.Write(Size);
        writer.Write(ContainerFileOffset);
    }
}
```

But I think a better way would be is creating a header before a file:

```
  File 1                                    File 2
+--------------------------+--------------+--------------------------+--------------+
| NextOffset|Filename|Size | FileData     | NextOffset|Filename|Size | FileData     |
+--------------------------+--------------+--------------------------+--------------+
```

This way you can easy add/remove files.

---

Another idea could be writing the fileinfolist at the end of the file. like:

```
+----------+----------+----------+---------------+------------------------------+
| Filedata | Filedata | Filedata | FileInfoTable | FileInfoTableOffset (4bytes) |
+----------+----------+----------+---------------+------------------------------+
```

The FileInfoTableOffset will point to the start address of the FileInfoTable. If you want to read the file, just put the whole FileInfoTable into the memory, when ready, write it back.

Comment: Firstly, thank you for your answer and advices. 

I'm currently using a FileStream with File.ReadAllBytes() to copy the file into the container but I will give a try to BinaryStream (I'm new with this kind of Stream)

The idea of adding a header before each file also came to my minde at the beginning, especially that I won't need to allocated space for a global header. I think I'll allocate a couple of bytes for NextOffset, Filename, Size so I can read then and access the data.

Using BinaryStream would be faster ?

Comment: I think using a BinaryWriter for writing file information will be faster than using xml. I'll update my answer for another idea.

Comment: Hi Jeroen, the FileInfoTable & offset at the end looks like a good idea. Do you think your method would be more efficient than the one I posted above ? I messed up a bit this morning using BinaryWritter, but maybe I'll retry. Anyway thanks for your suggestions !

Answer (score 1):

I tried a different way.

I created a serializable class like this :

```
[Serializable]
public class FileEntry
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public byte[] Content { get; set; }
}
```

In the class handling files :

```
public void AddFiles(string[] Files)
{
    int index = _files.Count;
    foreach (string file in Files)
    {
    {
        _files.Add(new FileEntry());
        _files[index].Name = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file);
        _files[index].Content = File.ReadAllBytes(file);
        index++;
    }

    byte[] bytes = null;
    BinaryFormatter serializer = new BinaryFormatter();
    using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        serializer.Serialize(memoryStream, _files);
        bytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
    }
    File.WriteAllBytes(_filePath, bytes);
}
```

And also :

```
public List<FileEntry> GetFiles()
{
    byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(_filePath);
    if (bytes.Length > 0)
    {
        BinaryFormatter serializer = new BinaryFormatter();
        using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(bytes))
            _files = serializer.Deserialize(memoryStream) as List<FileEntry>;
    }
    return _files;
}
```

It currently works like a charm :)